# How to use auth0 with angular universal

Tags: angular, typescript, auth0, angular-universal

I tried to add server side rendering for my angular 2+ application in order to use SEO.

Now I get a problem because of using auth0-js.

Console output is the following:

```
ERROR { TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined at WebAuth.parseHash (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\auth0-js\src\web-auth\index.js:138:53) at e.handleAuthentication (C:\Dev\frontend\dist\server.js:8:523298) at new e (C:\Dev\frontend\dist\server.js:8:161974) at createClass (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12509:20) at createDirectiveInstance (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12 ) at createViewNodes (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:13815:53) at createRootView (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:13704:5) at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\ s\core.umd.js:14397:12) at ComponentFactory_.create (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:1 6) at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\c d.js:4070:29) __zone_symbol__currentTask: ZoneTask { _zone: Zone { _properties: [Object], _parent: [Object], _name: 'angular', _zoneDelegate: [Object] }, runCount: 0, _zoneDelegates: null, _state: 'notScheduled', type: 'microTask', source: 'Promise.then', data: undefined, scheduleFn: undefined, cancelFn: null, callback: [Function], invoke: [Function] } } Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: { TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined at WebAuth.parseHash (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\auth0-js\src\web-auth\index.js:138:53) at e.handleAuthentication (C:\Dev\frontend\dist\server.js:8:523298) at new e (C:\Dev\frontend\dist\server.js:8:161974) at createClass (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12509:20) at createDirectiveInstance (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12 354:37) at createViewNodes (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:13815:53) at createRootView (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:13704:5) at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\ bundles\core.umd.js:14397:12) at ComponentFactory_.create (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:1 1299:46) at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\c ore.umd.js:4070:29) __zone_symbol__currentTask: ZoneTask { _zone: Zone { _properties: {}, _parent: null, _name: '<root>', _zoneDelegate: [Object] }, runCount: 0, _zoneDelegates: null, _state: 'notScheduled', type: 'microTask', source: 'Promise.then', data: undefined, scheduleFn: undefined, cancelFn: null, callback: [Function], invoke: [Function] } } TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined at WebAuth.parseHash (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\auth0-js\src\web-auth\index.js:138:53) at e.handleAuthentication (C:\Dev\frontend\dist\server.js:8:523298) at new e (C:\Dev\frontend\dist\server.js:8:161974) at createClass (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12509:20) at createDirectiveInstance (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12 354:37) at createViewNodes (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:13815:53) at createRootView (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:13704:5) at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\ bundles\core.umd.js:14397:12) at ComponentFactory_.create (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:1 1299:46) at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\c ore.umd.js:4070:29)
```

I used the default code from auth0 example:

```
public handleAuthentication(): void {
this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    window.location.hash = '';
    this.setSession(authResult);
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  } else if (err) {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    console.log(err);
    alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further details.`);
  }
});
```

}

**UPDATE:**

I added angular universal gotchas to my auth service.

Now I get the following new error as soon as I open localhost:4200:

```
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
at resolvePromise (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:824:31)
at resolvePromise (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:795:17)
at C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:873:17
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:425:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:4783:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:424:36)
at Zone.runTask (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:192:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:602:35)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:503:21)
at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (C:\Dev\frontend\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:488:48) rejection: { [Error]
 __zone_symbol__currentTask:
  ZoneTask {
    _zone: [Object],
    runCount: 0,
    _zoneDelegates: null,
    _state: 'notScheduled',
    type: 'microTask',
    source: 'Promise.then',
    data: undefined,
    scheduleFn: undefined,
    cancelFn: null,
    callback: [Function],
    invoke: [Function] } }, promise: ZoneAwarePromise {
 __zone_symbol__state: 0,
 __zone_symbol__value: { [Error] __zone_symbol__currentTask: [Object] } }, zone: Zone {
 _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
 _parent:
  Zone {
    _properties: {},
    _parent: null,
    _name: '<root>',
    _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
 _name: 'angular',
 _zoneDelegate:
  ZoneDelegate {
    _taskCounts: [Object],
    zone: [Circular],
    _parentDelegate: [Object],
    _forkZS: null,
    _forkDlgt: null,
    _forkCurrZone: [Object],
    _interceptZS: null,
    _interceptDlgt: null,
    _interceptCurrZone: [Object],
    _invokeZS: [Object],
    _invokeDlgt: [Object],
    _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
    _handleErrorZS: [Object],
    _handleErrorDlgt: [Object],
    _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
    _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
    _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object],
    _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
    _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
    _invokeTaskDlgt: [Object],
    _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
    _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
    _cancelTaskDlgt: [Object],
    _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
    _hasTaskZS: [Object],
    _hasTaskDlgt: [Object],
    _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular],
    _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } }, task: ZoneTask {
 _zone:
  Zone {
    _properties: [Object],
    _parent: [Object],
    _name: 'angular',
    _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
 runCount: 0,
 _zoneDelegates: null,
 _state: 'notScheduled',
 type: 'microTask',
 source: 'Promise.then',
 data: undefined,
 scheduleFn: undefined,
 cancelFn: null,
 callback: [Function],
 invoke: [Function] } }
```

Does someone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

window, document and other browser objects are not defiend when on server side.

You can add platform specific code which executes only if you are server side or client side.

https://github.com/angular/universal#universal-gotchas

Note: I haven't see the example code, but I'm not even sure that resettign the hash is useful here if ou are navigating to "/" after anyway

Comment: Thats correct. I thought the same as you did. I already added the universal-gotchas but I do not get httpclient requests to work.